# UL height incorrect. related to transform-origin or perspective-origin or -webkit-min-logical-width

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am implementing account page from Rokaux M-store template. For some reason it looks different in my machine.

Difference is UL height which is 0px whereas it should be 57px in original. Other computed items different were transform-origin or perspective-origin or -webkit-min-logical-width.

Where does the difference come from?

It should look like:
[image]

However it looks like 
[image]

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Thank you Quentin for great solution! I have always done like that, but in this case there was too much code that could have affected to paste here as a lot of things could have affected it. It would have taken hours and now it was solved in a few minutes with the help of Jyoi.

Comment: If there was too much code, then you didn't create a [mcve]. While Jyoti Pathania might have solved your problem, the result is a junk question, of no use to anybody in the future, that is cluttering up Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is with the `float`

Just add this style to your CSS. Make `.nav-tabs > li` to `float: none`;

Make this style more specific to this section only, by referring it with some `custom class` to parent. eg: `.customClass .nav-tabs > li`.

CSS:

```
.nav-tabs > li {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Comment: @MargusPala Your Welcome :)